# New Tor HIdden service specification

Tags: onion-services

i am doing some background research for my PhD on anonymity networks

i read that there is going to be some pretty major changes to hidden services but can not find an accurate up to date list of all the changes that are hopefully going to be implemented, documentation on the newer H.S. structure etc

i was wondering if anyone knows of any such documentation, or could give a brief summary of the changes

Thanks :)

Comment: Does [proposal 224](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/224-rend-spec-ng.txt), Next-Generation hidden services in tor, help at all? That should be the best documentation of the current state.

Answer (score 2):

A 'brief summary' is available in the [Tor-blog](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/hidden-service-hackfest-arlington-accords):

> Proposal 224 aka the "Next Generation Hidden Services" project is a plan for improving hidden services in fundamental ways: The new system
>   will be faster, use better cryptography, have more secure onion
>   addresses, and offer advanced security properties like improved DoS
>   resistance and keeping identity keys offline

Other possible changes are:

- [Merging](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2015-July/009079.html) the roles of "hidden service directory" and "introduction point" on the hidden service protocol
- A protocol for [global randomness calculation](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2015-August/009189.html)
- Defending Against [Guard Discovery Attacks](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2015-July/009066.html) using Vanguards
- [Revamped](https://gitweb.torproject.org/user/special/torspec.git/log/?h=xxx-direct-onion) "Direct Onion Services" into a faster and far more elegant protocol
- [OnioNS](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2015-July/009103.html), the Onion Name System, which allows a hidden service operator to register a human-readable name.

and [more](https://people.torproject.org/~asn/hs_hackfest_2015/224modules.txt)..

Read the [Next-Generation Hidden Services in Tor](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/224-rend-spec-ng.txt) document to know more.